# list all imports recursively from a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep, ripgrep

I am reorganising a react codebase and I would like to write a bash script which I can give a path to a component which lists all the files imported from that file recursively.

The output should be filtered by unique occurrences. I am only interested in the source files (aliased to @browse) (not node modules etc).

so far I have

```bash
#!/bin/bash

list_browse_imports() {
  rg "from '@browse" $1 | sed "s,.*@browse,," | sed "s/'//"
}

list_browse_imports $1
```

which yields:

```
/search/template/template
/product/button/button
```

I then want to feed these lines onward to rg (feel free to substitute to grep) again to match all the files in the tree that match that like

```bash
#!/bin/bash

list_browse_imports() {
  rg "from '@browse" $1 | sed "s,.*@browse,," | sed "s/'//" | xargs rg -l 
}

list_browse_imports $1
```

but this yields nothing.

I have tried to extract the second part to it's own function but get stuck there as well.

EDIT:

made some progress with this very ugly (and slow) code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

list_imports_rec() {
declare IMPORTS=$(rg "from '@browse" $1 | sed "s,.*@browse,," | sed "s/'//")

declare FILES=$(rg -l '')

#echo "RESULT IS $IMPORTS RESULT IS"
for import in $(rg "from '@browse" $1 | sed "s,.*@browse,," | sed "s/'//")
  do
    for file in $(rg -l '')
    do
      declare import_stripped=$(echo $import | sed "s,/,,g")
      declare file_stripped=$(echo $file | sed "s,/,,g")
      #echo "$import_stripped and $file_stripped"
      if [[ "$file_stripped" =~ .*"$import_stripped".* ]]; then
          echo "$file"
          list_imports_rec $file
      fi
    done
  done
}

list_imports_rec $1
```

Comment: `again to match all the files in the tree that match that like` match what? You want to list all lines in all files that contain the string `/search/template/template` __or__ string `/product/button/button`?

Comment: An easy optimization would be to use `$FILES` rather than call `rg -l ''` many times.  That has to be slooooow if there are many files.    But you're still processing all files, which seems entirely unnecessary when you have lists of specific files to search.

Comment: The first oversight is that you need the form   xargs rg -l '{}' \;   to ensure only one data line is used for each rg -l instance.   Other than that, am I correct to say that for  /search/template/template , you want only  template,  and for  /product/button/button , you want only button ?  If so, that is not obvious from what you provide in the original question.  If so,  add      | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF }'    to the original command .

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] so we can help more.